# Error on second selection for same code in lightning code works fine for first time but second time it gives error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, aura-attribute, aura-iteration

This code runs fine for first selection and also for first time but for second selection it gives following error

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
>   Action failed: c:Persmissionset$controller$onSelectChange [component.find(...).get is not a function]
>   Failing descriptor: {c:Persmissionset$controller$onSelectChange}

And on again selecting the first one it again gives error.

Can anyone check this

My component code is -

```
<aura:component controller="Persmissionset" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:attribute name="set" type="PermissionSetAssignment[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="page" type="integer" description="using for store page Number"/>
<aura:attribute name="pages" type="integer" description="using for store All Pages page Number"/>
<aura:attribute name="total" type="integer" description="total records count store "/>
  <aura:attribute name="met" type="PermissionSetAssignment[]"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="pagem" type="integer" description="using for store page Number"/>
<aura:attribute name="pagesm" type="integer" description="using for store All Pages page Number"/>
<aura:attribute name="totalm" type="integer" description="total records count store "/>

   <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[
    {'label': 'BusinessUsers', 'value': 'option1'},
    {'label': 'TechnicalUsers', 'value': 'option2'},                                                  
    ]"/>

    <aura:attribute name="value" type="String" default="option1"/>

    <lightning:radioGroup name="BVAdministrator"
                          label=""
                          options="{! v.options }"
                          value="{! v.value }"
                          type="radio"
                          class="customRadioCls"

                          />


      <aura:if isTrue="{!v.value == 'option1'}">

          <div class="slds-page-header" role="banner">
        <div class="slds-float--right">
        <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
              <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" style="width:90px" onclick="{!c.downloadCsv}">Download</button> <br/><br/>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate"> 

         <div class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-left_large" style="width:5px"> 
         <div class="slds-text-body_regular">  
              <lightning:button disabled="{!v.pagem == 1}" variant="brand" label="Previous" onclick="{! c.navigatem }" />            
              <lightning:button disabled="{!v.pagem == v.pagesm}" aura:id="Previous" variant="brand" label="Next" onclick="{! c.navigatem }"/>
         </div>
         </div>
            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:0rem">        
            <input type="text" id="search-text-input" class="slds-input slds-size--1-of-4 slds-text-body--small slds-text-color_weak slds-text-font_monospace" placeholder="Search" onkeyup="{!c.searchKeyevt}"/>
            <lightning:icon class="slds-input__icon slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_small slds-icon-text-default" iconName="utility:search" size="x-small" alternativeText="icon" />
                                </div>

         <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
         <div class="slds-xxx-around_small">{!v.totalm} Users Listing • page {!v.pagem} / {!v.pagesm}</div>
         </div>
         <div class="slds-xxx-around_small">
         <div class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-left_large" style="width:90px"> 
         <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
              <ui:inputSelect aura:id="recordSizes" label="Display per page: " change="{!c.onMelectChange}">
               <ui:inputSelectOption text="20" label="20" value="true"/>
                  <ui:inputSelectOption text="50" label="50" />
                  <ui:inputSelectOption text="100" label="100"/>
                   <ui:inputSelectOption text="1000" label="All"/>





     </aura:if>



 <aura:if isTrue="{!v.value == 'option2'}">

        <div class="slds-page-header" role="banner">
        <div class="slds-float--right">
        <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
              <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" style="width:90px" onclick="{!c.downloadCsv}">Download</button> <br/><br/>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate"> 

         <div class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-left_large" style="width:5px"> 
         <div class="slds-text-body_regular">  
              <lightning:button disabled="{!v.page == 1}" variant="brand" label="Previous" onclick="{! c.navigate }" />            
              <lightning:button disabled="{!v.page == v.pages}" aura:id="Previous" variant="brand" label="Next" onclick="{! c.navigate }"/>
         </div>
         </div>
            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:0rem">        
            <input type="text" id="search-text-input" class="slds-input slds-size--1-of-4 slds-text-body--small slds-text-color_weak slds-text-font_monospace" placeholder="Search" onkeyup="{!c.searchKeyevt}"/>
            <lightning:icon class="slds-input__icon slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_small slds-icon-text-default" iconName="utility:search" size="x-small" alternativeText="icon" />
                                </div>

         <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
         <div class="slds-xxx-around_small">{!v.total} Users Listing • page {!v.page} / {!v.pages}</div>
         </div>
         <div class="slds-xxx-around_small">
         <div class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-left_large" style="width:90px"> 
         <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
              <ui:inputSelect aura:id="recordSize" label="Display per page: " change="{!c.onSelectChange}">
               <ui:inputSelectOption text="20" label="20" value="true"/>
              <ui:inputSelectOption text="50" label="50"/>
              <ui:inputSelectOption text="100" label="100"/>
              <ui:inputSelectOption text="1000" label="All"/>
              </ui:inputSelect>
         </div>
         </div>
         </div>
         </div>


            </aura:if>

</aura:component>
```

Controller code is -

```
 doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
      // this function call on the component load first time     
      // get the page Number if it's not define, take 1 as default
      var page = component.get("v.page") || 1;
      // get the select option (drop-down) values.   
      var recordToDisply = component.find("recordSize").get("v.value");
      // call the helper function   
     helper.getPermissions(component, page, recordToDisply);   

         var pagem = component.get("v.pagem") || 1;
      // get the select option (drop-down) values.   
      var recordToDisplym = component.find("recordSizes").get("v.value");
      // call the helper function   
     helper.metPermissions(component, pagem, recordToDisplym);   

   },
     navigate: function(component, event, helper) {
      // this function call on click on the previous page button  
      var page = component.get("v.page") || 1;
      // get the previous button label  
      var direction = event.getSource().get("v.label");
      // get the select option (drop-down) values.  
      var recordToDisply = component.find("recordSize").get("v.value");
      // set the current page,(using ternary operator.)  
      page = (direction == "Previous" ? (page-1) : (page + 1));
      // call the helper function
   helper.getPermissions(component, page, recordToDisply);


   },

    navigatem: function(component, event, helper) {
      // this function call on click on the previous page button  
      var pagem = component.get("v.pagem") || 1;
      // get the previous button label  
      var direction = event.getSource().get("v.label");
      // get the select option (drop-down) values.  
      var recordToDisplym = component.find("recordSizes").get("v.value");
      // set the current page,(using ternary operator.)  
      pagem = (direction == "Previous" ? (page-1) : (page + 1));
      // call the helper function
   helper.metPermissions(component, pagem, recordToDisplym);

 },

   onSelectChange: function(component, event, helper) {
      // this function call on the select opetion change,    
      var page = 1
      var recordToDisply = component.find("recordSize").get("v.value");
      helper.getPermissions(component, page, recordToDisply);

   },

    onMelectChange: function(component, event, helper) {
      // this function call on the select opetion change,    
      var pagem = 1
      var recordToDisplym = component.find("recordSizes").get("v.value");
      helper.metPermissions(component, pagem, recordToDisplym);

   },
```

Comment: Just a tummy feeling: check out if `component.find()` returns the same value for both calls. We experienced `find()` returning (as expected) `component` but also `[component]`, so you'd need to call `component.find()[0].get()`

Comment: Please do make sure to use the `{}` tool to format your code when you post.

Comment: @ChristianSzandorKnapp how it will work iam confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in lightning aura conditional rendering `aura:if`. If you unrender and rerender immediately (*i.e.,* When `isTrue` condition becomes `false` and immediately `true`) then the components do not get unrendered properly. So, from next transaction onwards `component.find` will be returning an array in which the first element (`0` index) will always be the one coming in UI.

**Solution:**

Change the `onSelectChange` controller.js method as below:

```
onSelectChange: function(component, event, helper) {
    var page = 1
    let recordSize = component.find("recordSize");
    recordSize = Array.isArray(recordSize) ? recordSize[0] : recordSize;
    var recordToDisply = recordSize.get("v.value");
    helper.getPermissions(component, page, recordToDisply);
},
```

Comment: Thanks A lot @salesforce-sas this works for me and thanks for sharing this valuable information .

Comment: I'm glad my tummy feeling was right. Thanks for elaborating, @salesforce-sas